# Gun doesn't update in realtime

Tags: reactjs, chat, p2p, gun

I have been building a simple chat app using gunjs. But apparently, the chat doesn't update in real time. I have to reload the page for the changes to reflect. I can't seem to figure out the problem. The chats are getting added but have to reload the page to get them from the get call. Any help will be really appreciated.

Code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import GUN, { SEA } from 'gun';
import { user } from '../auth/userAuth';
import ChatMsg from './ChatMsg';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';


function Chat() {
  const db = GUN();

  const [newMessage, setnewMessage] = useState('');
  const [messages, setmessages] = useState([]);

  const username = useSelector((state) => state.user.value.username);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(db.get('chat'));

    db.get('chat').on((data, id) => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    db.get('chat')
      .map()
      .on(async (data, id) => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data) {
          const key = '#kewk';
          const message = {
            who: await db.user(data).get('alias'),
            what: data.what,
            when: GUN.state.is(data, 'what'),
          };
          console.log(message);
          setmessages((old) =>
            [...old.slice(-100), message].sort((a, b) => a.when - b.when)
          );
        }
      });
  }, []);

  const sendMsg = async () => {
    
    const message = user.get('all-msg').set({ what: newMessage });
    console.log(message);
    const index = new Date().toISOString();
    db.get('chat').set(message);
    setnewMessage('');
  };
  return (
    <div className="chatbox">
      <div className="all-chats">
        {messages.map((message, index) => {
          return <ChatMsg message={message} sender={username} key={index} />;
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="message-input-cont">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="new-message"
          placeholder="Enter message"
          value={newMessage}
          onChange={(e) => setnewMessage(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <button onClick={sendMsg}></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Chat;
```

my userAuth file looks like this :

```
import GUN from 'gun';
import 'gun/sea';

import { updateUsername } from '../features/user';
import { store } from '../store/store';


//Database
export const db = GUN();

//User
export const user = db.user().recall({ sessionStorage: true });

db.get('alias').on((v) => store.dispatch(updateUsername({ username: v })));

db.on('auth', async (event) => {
  const alias = await user.get('alias'); // username string
  store.dispatch(updateUsername({ username: alias }));
  console.log(`signed in as ${alias}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

best place to get help on bugs and stuff is http://chat.gun.eco

From a quick glance, it looks like 2 things:

(1) You do not have AXE included

(this is a good thing tho, as AXE is in alpha as of September 2021)

(2) If you do not have AXE included, you have to manually connect peers with `GUN(peers)`

How do you connect to another browser? WebRTC unfortunately needs a "signaling" server, so we run a bunch of decentralized GUN peers that act as relays with built in signaling. You can run your own by just `npm start` in an npm installed GUN repo.

`GUN(['http://localhost:8765/gun', ...otherPeersHere])`

AXE will automatically handle peer connection, discovery, clustering, and relaying for you. But it (September 2021) is not working yet.